# Build Error: "Files has invalid value..."

Tags: vb.net, visual-studio-2015, compiler-errors

When trying to build my project in VS2015 I am getting an error "Files has invalid value", followed by the path to my project with " - Copy" appended to it. This is followed by a long string of characters, mostly diamonds with a "?" in them.

Project has been working well until my system blue screened this morning.

Once I had the system back up I am getting the error. The project also showed one of the ActiveReports VB files was missing, so I restored it from a backup. I have tried renaming the My Projects folder, to no avail.

Comment: Did you restore the hole project? there seems to be more files corrupted,

Comment: I could restore from a backup, however I had some work done after the backup was created that I hoped to not lose.

Comment: yes, i know. Compare the files of the backup with your actual project folder. .First you can try to restore Form by form module b module and see if the changed files are ok. if you are lucky none of the changed are corrupt..

Comment: Thanks for trying to help. In the end I went to a backup and re-created the lost work.